# add pairs with a rule to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I obtained a list:

```
(original list)
 list1=
 {{-2.25, 24},
 {-2.24, 0},
 {-2.23, 0},
 {-2.22, 10},
 {-2.21, 32},
 {-2.20, 50}};
```

I am motivated to create another list in which some pairs `(x,y)` add to the first list according to a law: `x:` brings from the *next* pair of original list and `y` repeats from the *past* pair in the original list.

```
list2=
 {{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 24},
 {-2.24, 0}, {-2.23, 0},
 {-2.23, 0}, {-2.22, 0},
 {-2.22, 10}, {-2.21, 10},
 {-2.21, 32}, {-2.20, 32},
 {-2.20, 50}}
```

Comment: `Riffle[list1, Transpose[{Rest[#1], Most[#2]}] & @@ Transpose[list1]]`?

Comment: I think you have mis-copied `list2`. I think you want it to be `list2 = {{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 24}, {-2.24, 0}, {-2.23, 0}, {-2.23, 
   0}, {-2.22, 0}, {-2.22, 10}, {-2.21, 10}, {-2.21, 32}, {-2.20, 
   32}, {-2.20, 50}}`

Comment: So sorry yes. You are right.

Comment: @J.M. your code is wonderful. I must see how that works.

Comment: @J.M. I have a crush on you because of your solution!!!

Comment: I'm not marrying you, sorry. ;)

Comment: So sorry if I could not tell the real mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Join @@ Developer`PartitionMap[If[Length@# === 1, #, {#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}}] &, 
 list1, 2, 1, 1, {}]  == list2
```

> True

```
Join @@ (If[Length@# === 1, #, {#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}}] & /@ 
    Partition[list1, 2, 1, 1, {}]) == list2
```

> True

Steps:

Partition `list` into parts of length up to 2 with offset 1 (take 2 elements move 1 step):

```
l1 = Partition[list1, 2, 1, 1, {}]
```

> {{{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 0}},
>      {{-2.24, 0}, {-2.23, 0}},
>      {{-2.23, 0}, {-2.22, 10}},
>      {{-2.22, 10}, {-2.21, 32}},
>      {{-2.21, 32}, {-2.2, 50}},
>      {{-2.2, 50}}}

The function

```
func = If[Length@# === 1, #, {#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}}] &;
```

leaves objects with `Length` 1 untouched, and, for two-element arguments modifies the second element to make its last entry equal to that of the first.
Applied to the first element of `l1` it gives

```
func @ l1[[1]]
```

> {{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 24}}

Mapped to each element of `l1` it gives

```
func /@ l1
```

> {{{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 24}},
>      {{-2.24, 0}, {-2.23, 0}},
>       {{-2.23,  0}, {-2.22, 0}},
>      {{-2.22, 10}, {-2.21, 10}},
>      {{-2.21, 32}, {-2.2, 32}},
>      {{-2.2, 50}}}

Flattening this gives `list2`.

`` Developer`PartititionMap[func, list, other arguments] `` is equivalent to `func /@ Partition[list, other arguments]`, that is, it applies the function to each element of the partition.

Comment: I do apologize for my question but I cannot understand the mean of ``Developer`PartitionMap`` . what does it mean!!!

Comment: @Irreversible, I updated with some explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ReplaceAll`

```
list = {{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 0}, {-2.23, 0}, {-2.22, 10}, {-2.21, 32}, {-2.20, 50}};

Append[Partition[list, 2, 1] /. {p : {_, a_}, {b_, _}} :> 
   Sequence[p, {b, a}], Last@list]
```

> {{-2.25, 24}, {-2.24, 24},
>   {-2.24, 0}, {-2.23, 0},
>    {-2.23, 0}, {-2.22,0},
>    {-2.22, 10}, {-2.21, 10},
>    {-2.21, 32}, {-2.2, 32},
>    {-2.2, 50}}

Or

```
Most@Catenate@MapThread[{#1, {First@#2, Last@#1}} &, {list, RotateLeft@list}]
```

Answer (score 3):

[J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s method is much faster than others provided, and deserves its own answer.

The champion:

```
fastJM[a_] := Riffle[a, {Rest[#1], Most[#2]}\[Transpose] & @@ (a\[Transpose])]
```

The contenders:

```
kglr[a_] :=
  Join @@ Developer`PartitionMap[
    If[Length@# === 1, #, {#[[1]], {#[[2, 1]], #[[1, 2]]}}] &, a, 2, 1, 1, {}]

eldo1[list_] :=
  Append[Partition[list, 2, 1] /. {p : {_, a_}, {b_, _}} :> 
    Sequence[p, {b, a}], Last@list];

eldo2[list_] :=
  Most@Catenate@MapThread[{#1, {First@#2, Last@#1}} &, {list, RotateLeft@list}]
```

My own contribution, a variation of J.M.'s [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html) code:

```
JMmod[a_] := Riffle[a, {a[[2 ;;, 1]], a[[;; -2, 2]]}\[Transpose]]
```

#### Benchmark

With a packed array of reals:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{fastJM, kglr, eldo1, eldo2, JMmod}, RandomReal[9, {#, 2}] &, 10]
```

[image]

With unpackable Strings:

```
BenchmarkPlot[{fastJM, kglr, eldo1, eldo2, JMmod},
  RandomChoice[Alphabet[], {#, 2}] &, 10]
```

[image]

It appears that my variation manages a slight edge on the original in the case of unpackable data, but it falls behind on a packed array.  None of the other methods come close in either test.

Comment: The comparison is amazing, +1,